# libcurl SSL connect error

Tags: macos, curl, libcurl

I have a weird situation where a **GET** request using **libcurl** works on Windows but gives a certificate error on **OSX** ("*SSL peer handshake failed, the server most likely requires a client certificate to connect*")

The weird part is that if I try the same request in the terminal using curl (still on OSX) it works fine.

The only SSL related options I'm using are

```
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

How to fix this?

```
Win7 curl version: 7.46
OSX Sierra curl version: 7:54
```

Comment: take whatever certificate bundle windows uses, and copy it over to OSX and tell curl to use it with CURLOPT_CAINFO ? although you can most likely use this 1: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: @hanshenrik and the users of the application would have to do the same ? That just doesn't seem right to me

Comment: nah, you can just ship an appropriate certificate bundle with the application.

Comment: but why does it work using curl if it's a certificate issue?

Comment: best guess: your windows system has a default certificate bundle installed that libcurl reads, your OSX system does not

Comment: @hanshenrik I meant that also on OSX curl works fine

Comment: okay, maybe the user account that the program that use libcurl does not have access to read the default certificate bundle, but the user account you run curl with does?

Comment: I'm running both with the same account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `curl` from OS X bash using **verbose output** (`-v`). It should give you information about the CA cURL is using, as docs say in the [verbose section](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-verbose.html):

> If we use an HTTPS:// URL instead of an HTTP one, there will also be a whole bunch of lines explaining how curl uses CA certs to verify the server's certificate and some details from the server's certificate, etc. Including which ciphers were selected and more TLS details.

**EDIT:**  [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST.html) is the explanation for my comment below, under "Limitations":

> DarwinSSL: If verify value is 0, then SNI is also disabled. SNI is a TLS extension that sends the hostname to the server. The server may use that information to do such things as sending back a specific certificate for the hostname, or forwarding the request to a specific origin server. Some hostnames may be inaccessible if SNI is not sent.

The problem here is that cURL uses DarwinSSL for OS X, which has a limitation with some hostnames when `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` is set to 0. Try to send the request without disabling those two opts.

Comment: This is the output I get https://pastebin.com/jb3mELjH . Which one is the client certificate ?

Comment: I took a look at the curl source. Here is the code snippet that throws the error you're getting. https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/vtls/darwinssl.c#L2326

Have you tried commenting out the two lines you showed in the question? Maybe you're explicitly telling curl not to verify host and peer, which is not supported by DarwinSSL, the TLS implementation for Darwin based OSes.
Try without disabling verifications.

Comment: That limitation is caused by the DarwinSSL's API so not something curl can do much about...